# Scala Simple calculation error

Tags: scala, math, operation

Hi I am new to Scala and the following behavior is really weird. Is Scala making mistake even for this simple calculation? Or I am doing something wrong? 
Thanks,

```
scala $ Welcome to Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val radius:Double = 10.2
radius: Double = 10.2

scala> radius * 10
res0: Double = 102.0

scala> radius * 100
res1: Double = 1019.9999999999999

scala> radius * 1000
res2: Double = 10200.0
```

Comment: Where's the mistake?

Comment: Real numbers like 100 are only approximated when represented in floating point. This might help http://fabiensanglard.net/floating_point_visually_explained/

Answer (score 2):

A `Double` in Scala is a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number equivalent to Java's double primitive type, as described in [Scala's doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Double.html).

By nature of [floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), a `Double` doesn't necessarily return the exact value of a number.  It boils down to the fact that decimals can't always be precisely represented as binary.

For better precision, you might want to consider using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

Real numbers are represented by Float (32-bit) and Double (64-bit). These are binary formats which only approximately represent the complete range of Real numbers. Real numbers include all the [Rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) (countable infinite), and the [Irrationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) (uncountable infinite). Double can at best represent only a small, finite subset of the Rationals.

The [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision) double precision floating point encoding uses 53-bit mantissa (52-bits explicitly stored), an 11-bit exponent, and 1-bit for sign. Read about IEEE Double precision floating point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

The range of integers which can be exactly represented is +/- 2^53-1, while the exponent represents a range of 10^+/-308.

- You cannot express an integer x exactly where |x| > 2^53.
- You cannot express fractions exactly which are not of the form k/2^n, where k, n are integers (and k, n are within above limits). Thus, you cannot represent 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/11, etc.
- Any rational fraction where the denominator is relatively prime to 2 cannot be exactly represented. Any fraction k/P, where P is the product of primes other than 2, and k is not a multiple of P, cannot be exactly represented by IEEE-754 floating point.

The behavior you are observing is due to 1/5 being approximately represented, and the conversion from internal double/float representation to character representation performs rounding to some precision. All languages which use machine floating point (double/float) exhibit similar behavior, but the routines which convert from float to print may round these approximate numbers differently.

*As a consequence of [Cantor's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) that the Real numbers are [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) and the Rational numbers are [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set), almost all Real numbers are irrational.*